# Fast motion cloth-simulation problem

Tags: cloth-simulation

Strange things happen to the dress when you move quickly or turn around.

Here's a video with the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/931fat4jpegahg3/wSdLfVG3Kq.mp4?dl=0

Cloth simulation settings:

[image]

Collision settings:
[image]

For all objects: scale = 1; position and rotation = 0.

Can anyone please help me with this problem, because I have no idea what I should do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the collision distance on the cloth simulation, it helps with clipping, but it also makes it "float" around the object if you add too much